# list all products and link each category grid with category box in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to load all categories grids on one page and want all products to be available on scroll down. currently I need to click on each category and the page refreshes for each category. This is the site I am working on(ahmad.esy.es). I want this type of functionality upon clicking the category(http://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-hertsplaice-en11/menu#2254). kindly suggest me what changes should I make in view files (product.tpl, category.tpl) or controller files(product.php, category.php). how can I load all the grids of categories in one page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look at the site you have posted above - if you cannot describe your issue by words or by submitting a code or image it should be improved.

From what I understand you just want an infinite scroll to display all the products you have in your eshop. It is not mentioned whether you want to preserve the default functionality (category tree with products attached to certain categories) or whether you want only this one listing - basically it does not matter - so I will describe in short how to *add* such new functionality.

1. The model

   - you do not need to touch any model - you can reuse the method `ModelCatalogProduct::getProducts()`
   - this will give you the possibility to sort or filter the products except you will have to omit the `filter_category_id` to load all the products
2. The controller

   - feel free to create a new controller (e.g. `ControllerProductInfinite`) or just to reuse one of the already existing - either `ControllerProductCategory` or `ControllerProductProduct`
   - all you need is basically the same as in `ControllerProductCategory::index()` except adding `filter_category_id` into a array passed when calling `ModelCatalogProduct::getProducts()` and a new template for rendering
3. The template

   - create a new template that will meet your expectations and *infinite scroll* requirements
   - stick to any *infinite scroll* plugin/implementation you like (may Google be with you)